# Draw Kolb Learning Style Circle

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw this image which is called Kolb Circle. I tried my best and I got stuck.

## Expected Output

[image: Kolb Circle]

## MWE

```
\documentclass[tikz,12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \r in {1,...,5}
  \draw[ thick] (0,0) circle (\r);    
  \foreach \r in {2, 4,...,10}
  \draw (.5*\r,0) node[inner sep=1pt,below=3pt,rectangle,fill=white] {$\r{0}\%$};

    \foreach \a in {0, 90,...,359}
  \draw[thick] (0, 0) -- (\a:5);

    \node(R0) at (5.5,0){RO};
    \node(R0) at (-5.5,0){AE};
    \node(R0) at (0,5.5){CE};
    \node(R0) at (0,-5.5){AC};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, aren't you. Unfortunately I cannot read the ticks from your screen shot, but if you tell me what they are, I'll be happy to add them. Now I am guessing them.

```
\documentclass[tikz,12pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[my ticks/.style={postaction={decorate,
 decoration={ markings,% switch on markings 
 mark=between positions 0 and 1 step 2.5mm
      with
      {
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myX}{mod(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark
      info/sequence number},4)-1}
      \ifnum\myX=0
      \else
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myL}{10+2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}}
      \draw (0pt,0pt) -- (0pt,-4pt) node[pos=2,font=\tiny]{\myL};
      \fi
      }
}}}]
    \foreach \r in {1,...,5}
  \draw[ thick] (0,0) circle (\r);    
  \foreach \r in {2, 4,...,10}
  \draw (45:0.5*\r+0.05) node[inner sep=1pt,above right,rectangle,fill=white] {$\r{0}\%$}
  (-135:0.5*\r+0.05) node[inner sep=1pt,below left,rectangle,fill=white] {$\r{0}\%$};

    \foreach \a in {0, 90,...,360}
  \draw[thick,my ticks] (0, 0) -- (\a:5);

    \node[rotate=90](R0) at (5.5,0){RO};
    \node[rotate=90] (AE) at (-5.5,0){AE};
    \node(CE) at (0,5.5){CE};
    \node(AC) at (0,-5.5){AC};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Still missing the small tick-marks.

Comment: @OOzyPal As I wrote, I can not read them in your screen shot. If you tell me what they are, it will be easy to add them.

Comment: @OOzyPal I added some ticks, but I really can't read your screen shot. The good news is that this way of adding the ticks is very flexible and also works if you ever decide to rotate the lines (what hard-coded foreach loops do not allow you to do so easily).

Answer (score 1):

This can still be simplified but seems working. Most of the code is for drawing the tics which I see can be simplified in a second attempt.

```
\documentclass[tikz,12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}     
 \foreach \r [count=\rcount, evaluate=\r as\p using int(2*\r)] in {1,...,5} {
   \draw [thick] circle (\r) (45:\r+.5) node{$\p{0}\%$} (225:\r+.5) node{$\p{0}\%$};

   \foreach \t [count=\tcount, evaluate=\t as\b using int(16-\tcount+4*\rcount)] in {.2,.5,.8} 
     \draw (\r-\t,0) -- (\r-\t,-2mm) node[below,font=\tiny]{\b};

   \foreach \t [count=\tcount, evaluate=\t as\b using int(18-\tcount+4*\rcount)] in {.2,.5,.8} 
     \draw (\t-\r,0) -- (\t-\r,2mm) node[above,font=\tiny]{\b};

   \foreach \t [count=\tcount, evaluate=\t as\b using int(15-\tcount+4*\rcount)] in {.2,.5,.8} 
     \draw (0,\r-\t) -- (2mm,\r-\t) node[right,font=\tiny]{\b};

   \foreach \t [count=\tcount, evaluate=\t as\b using int(20-\tcount+4*\rcount)] in {.2,.5,.8} 
     \draw (0,\t-\r) -- (-2mm,\t-\r) node[left,font=\tiny]{\b};   
 }    
 \draw[thick] (180:5)node[left]{AE} -- (0:5)node[right]{RO} (90:5)node[above]{CE} -- (-90:5)node[below]{AC};    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]